# adding image into existing pdf

Tags: java

i just want add image into existing pdf that i tried, but it replace the code that i dont want.I just want to insert image at perticular location with previous data.and image should not replace that data.

Answer (score 1):

[iText http://itextpdf.com/](http://itextpdf.com/) lets you do this kind of things